# Julia flisp jl-parse-file returning #f

Tags: parsing, julia

I'm trying to test the Julia parser using the `flisp` frontend. I followed the documentation and ran the following commands:

```
cd src
flisp/flisp
(load "jlfrontend.scm")
(jl-parse-file "<filename>")
```

However, the last command returns `#f` instead of parsing the file. The file `<filename>` exists in the current directory (src) and `jlfrontend.scm` is also present. I'm not sure why `jl-parse-file` is failing.

1. What could be causing the `jl-parse-file` function to return `#f`?
2. Are there any additional steps I need to take to ensure successful parsing?
3. Is there a different approach I can take to test the Julia parser outside of rebuilding the project?